# OpenGL - Map points on a surface

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I am looking for a technique in OpenGL that I can use in order to map color points on a surface.
Each point is defining a display color and three coordinates (X, Y, Z).
The surface on which to map those data is built from all the points' coordinates in the main usage (complex shape) but can be built normally from standard shape such as a cone or a sphere.
Since there are voids between the points (for example one millimeter step between two points along the X axis), it would be also needed to interpolate the points data on the surface.
I am thinking about building bitmaps from the points and then applying those bitmaps on my surfaces but I am wondering if OpenGL does have a feature that allow to do that in a "smart way".

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking, but generally OpenGL consists of you doing the smart conversion from your data format to their simple graphics format of vertex coordinates and a color to go along with each vertex (or a texture coordinate to go along with each vertex and some vertex data, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you are asking for is basic OpenGl behaviour.

If you draw a triangle:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);     
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);     // Red
    glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Top vertex
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);     // Green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom left vertex
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);     // Blue
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom right vertex
glEnd();
```

The result is a smoothly ( if garishly) coloured solid triangle.

So your problem is to construct a series of polygons (possibly just triangles) which cover your surface and have the point set as vertices.

For a great intro to OpenGl, see [NeHe's tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net), including the above example.

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of points (more than 4 millions) to draw. I am currently using VBO to do that but the result is just a cloud of points. I can create triangles and then display them, but I am wondering if OpenGL doesn't have a feature like that, that I could use directly instead of implementing my own (everyone is lazy, don't blame me :P)

Comment: @Toyo. Ah... A lot more interesting. Apologies for the perhaps patronising initial answer. Looking forward to seeing a good answer. I know of nothing in OpenGl to do this directly. Have you tried just creating a triangle on the fly based on the vertex coordinates (need to be able to guess the normal from the location?)

Comment: No problem Keith, no offense taken :). That is a solution I tried. In fact I am trying to get two results. The first one is to have a volume with all the points. The colors are from 0% to 100%, 0% meaning void. So I adjust automatically the alpha channel to have the "voids" not displayed. But as soon as we zoom in, we can see the discrete data... I am looking for a solution but for now I am looking for the solution of previously said problem. I really don't want to do interpolation because the amount of points is just too huge...

Comment: How are you generating the points? Can you do it such that consecutive points are localised such that triples represent triangles on the surface, i.e. use a GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP?

Comment: The points are generated by a physical system. The points are in fact obtained from a sampling of an ultrasonic beam, so I can't make any modifications on this. On another website, someone talked about an interesting feature called "depth map". It is quite interesting but I need to investigate it more